# where is subiquity's snap gone?

Tags: snap, subiquity

I was playing with snap subiquity and installed it with following command :

```bsh
snap download --channel edge subiquity
```

Then I did a snap list

```bsh
$snap list
Name                             Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
autoinstall-generator            0.1.0                       64     latest/stable    dbungert    -
core18                           20210611                    2074   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20                           20210702                    1081   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804                  3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804                  0+git.3556cb3               72     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes                0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0                      4      latest/stable    kde✓        -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20  5.79.0                      14     latest/stable    kde✓        -
snap-store                       3.38.0-64-g23c4c77          547    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapcraft                        4.8.3                       6596   latest/stable    canonical✓  classic
snapd                            2.51.3                      12704  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

Don't see any trace of subiquity's snap in this list.
Checked `/snap` and `/var/lib/snapd/snaps` and nothing to be seen neither.

What did i miss ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question as it was a silly one after all.
`snap download` doesn't mean `snap install` : the first fetches the snap package and the other effectively install it on the system.

So the missing part was

```bsh
snap ack subiquity_2584.assert
snap install subiquity_2584.snap
```

But not a good idea to install subiquity on a Desktop as advertised by the warning. Better do that on a VM.